# Equivalent definitions of real analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) on analytic functions gives three different characterizations of the definition of real analytic functions, and I was wondering if anyone could explain how I might go about proving one of the equivalences, namely between definitions (1) and (3), which I will rewrite here below.

TFAE,

(1) A function $f$ is real analytic on some open set $D$

(3) $f$ is real smooth and for every compact $K \subset D$ there is some $C$ such that for every $x \in K$ and every $k \geq 0$ the following inequality is true

$\begin{equation}
|f^{(i)} (x)| \leq C^{k+1}k!
\end{equation}$

I believe that I understand the notion of a function being real analytic on an open set $D$ in what I imagine is the usual way: $f$ is real analytic if $\forall d \in D:\exists r > 0$ such that $\forall d_0 \in V_r(d)$ (the $r$-neighborhood centered at $d$), the Taylor series $T_f (d_0)$ converges to $f(d_0)$. My experience with Taylor series is not very extensive, and my lack of understanding is probably holding me back a lot here; specifically, I have a hard time seeing the link between definitions (1) and (3).

As in definition (3), I would imagine that bounding the value of the derivative $f^{(i)}$ is a way of guaranteeing convergence of the series, but I'm really just not sure. I'm hoping someone here could give me some intuition or motivation for proving this equivalence.

Comment: what means TFAE?

Comment: The Following Are Equivalent, i.e., (1) iff (3)